# Codeigniter send mail: attachment damaged

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3, email-attachments

I create with PHPPowerpoint a .pptx file and save it to the Server. The user has now 2 options within the Website:

1. Download file directly: This works fine. File is opened without any error.
2. Send mail himself with file attached: Mail is send correctly, however the attached .pptx says it is damaged when I try to open it.

This is my php code to send the mail:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'xxx';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('xxx', 'xxx');
$this->email->to('xxx');

$this->email->subject($_POST['id']." ".$_POST['title']);
$this->email->message('See attachment.');
$this->email->attach($filepath);
$this->email->send();
```

I have opened both files with 7zip and mentioned, that the file Content_types.xml could not be opened for the file sent by mail.

What could be wrong and how to fix it?

This is the correct Header that is missing when sending the pptx vai mail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
  <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/presentation.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.main+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideMasters/slideMaster1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideMaster+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout3.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout4.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout5.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout6.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout7.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout8.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout9.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout10.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout11.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/ppt/slides/slide1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide+xml"/>
  <Default Extension="gif" ContentType="image/gif"/>
  <Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>
  <Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>
  <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
  <Default Extension="xlsx" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>
</Types>
```

Comment: could you show me the `source code` of the email?

Comment: What exactly do you need? There are many IP addresses and I do not want to make them public.

Comment: I want to see the content-type of the attachment in the email source code; maybe it is not properly detected by codeigniter

Comment: C o n t e n t - T y p e :   m u l t i p a r t / m i x e d ;

Comment: not the content-type of the email, but the part's

Comment: The Content_types.XML is missing for the mail sent by mail. Expected Content_types.XML added in my question.

Comment: The attached file should be identical to the one display to the user.

Comment: That is my problem: It is the identical file however after sending by codeigniter mail the coontent_types.XML is missing.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird, I don't think that codeigniter modifies the file.

Comment: I have now created a .txt file on the server with some content. The .txt sent by mail misses the first 57 characters. I have no idea what it could be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this one as working solution: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4746

"There is an issue which occurs in  /system/libraries/Email.php  on line  1471  when you add attachments to an email and none of them have a  Content-ID ."

```
 .(empty($this->_attachments[$i]['cid']) ? '' : 'Content-ID: <'.$this->_attachments[$i]['cid'].'>'.$this->newline).$this->newline
```

It should be fixed with CI 3.1.0 but it does not work for me at all. Modifying line 1471 helps.

Comment: If this does not work, then please do not post another problem as a solution.  This should be an addendum to your OP instead.

Comment: The problem should not exist with CI 3.1.0, but it is also there. Modifying line 1471 helps.

Comment: Again, instead of actually answering the original question, you're just adding another question/problem.  That's not the correct way to use this site.  The "Answers" section is only for posting a solution to the original problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Again, modifying line 1471 solves the problem and thus it is the answer to my problem. Thanks.